# Chrome: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in Codeigniter view

Tags: javascript, ajax

The following code snippet results in a javascript error pointing at the line 'fail: function()' The error is:   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier and also fails in Firefox

```
        $.ajax(
                    {
                        type:"post",
                        url: "http://hdkumdo.com/gumdo/manage_members/view",
                        data:{ email:email},
                        done:function(response)
                        {
                            console.log('Done' + response);
                        }
                        fail: function() 
                        {
                            console.log('Failed');
                        }
                    });
```

The full function below works when the ajax code is commented out:

```
  $( ".row_button" ).click(function() {
       var email= "hello" ;           
       $('#membertbl').find('tr').click( function(){
          var ID = $(this).find('td:first').text();
          console.log('You selected ID: ' + ID);

/*      $.ajax(
                {
                    type:"post",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>manage_members/view",
                    data:{ email:email},
                    done:function(response)
                    {
                        console.log('Done' + response);
                    }
                    fail: function() 
                    {
                        console.log('Failed');
                    }
                }); */
     });
});
```

Comment: `done:function(response)
                        {
                           ...
                        }` **,**. <-- comma missing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667416/javascript-error-unexpected-identifier-when-trying-to-do-jquery-ajax-call

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a comma in your properties list.
Also there is no fail and done config properties in jQuery ajax, what you're looking for is `success` and `error`

```
    $.ajax(
                {
                    type:"post",
                    url: "http://hdkumdo.com/gumdo/manage_members/view",
                    data:{ email:email},
                    success:function(response)
                    {
                        console.log('Done' + response);
                    },
                    error: function() 
                    {
                        console.log('Failed');
                    }
    });
```

Comment: Many thanks to Musa and Adelin. Re done and fail..I derived that from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20597445/jquery-ajax-done-callback-not-firing but thanks for the info.

Comment: `done` and `fail` is chained to `$.ajax`, i.e. `$.ajax().done().fail()` and not a property